# How to customise checkboxes

Tags: javascript, css, razor, checkbox

How to edit checkboxes to looks like this:
[checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCujy.png)
I didn't find anything on Bootstrap.

Currently my checkbox list looks like this:
[Unmodified checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeZpt.png)

In my cshtml I have empty div which I populate from javascript.

```
<div id="check-list-box" class="list-group checked-list-box">

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
for (i = 0; i < brUredjaja; i++) {
  var brParametara = data[i].series.length;

  if ((brParametara > 1) || (brUredjaja > 1)) {
    for (j = 0; j < brParametara; j++) {
      {
        $("#graphId").append("<div class='graphReport col-md-6' id = div" + i + "dev" + j + "></div>");
        $('#check-list-box').append('<input type="checkbox" checked id="myCheckbox" />' + data[i].series[j].name);
        InitGraph(data[i].dates, data[i].series[j].data, "div" + i + "dev" + j, data[i].series[j].name, data[i].deviceName);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Click Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp) have a look at the website might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Add classname to the checkboxes, and edit its CSS. 
[This link](https://freefrontend.com/css-checkboxes/) will lead you to some examples you can get "how to"s from.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code for custom checkbox -

```css
.custom-checkbox{
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: arial;
  padding-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
 }
 .custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]+span:before {
     content: "";
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     border: 2px solid #383a43;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
 }
 .custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]+span:after {
     content: "";
     width: 10px;
     height: 5px;
     border-left: 2px solid;
     border-bottom: 2px solid;
     position: absolute;
     left: 5px;
     top: 6px;
     transform: rotate(-39deg);
     visibility: hidden;
     opacity: 0;
     transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }
 .custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]{display: none;}
 .custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span:after{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
 }
```

```html
<label class="custom-checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox" />
 <span>Checkbox 1</span>
</label>
<br>
<label class="custom-checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox" />
 <span>Checkbox 2</span>
</label>
<br>
<label class="custom-checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox" />
 <span>Checkbox 3</span>
</label>
<br>
<label class="custom-checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox" />
 <span>Checkbox 4</span>
</label>
```